# Simple equation not calculating as expected

Tags: java

```java
System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (240 - 20)) * (27 - 20));
//Should print 295.5 but prints 300

System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (240 - 20)) * (26 - 20));
//Should print 296.1 but prints 300
```

I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong with this simple equation. I've tried storing the variable in **ints**, **doubles**, and **floats** then printing it out, and I still get 300.

I have put the equation into different calculators like Google and http://web2.0calc.com/, and they produce the correct answers.

Please help me.

Comment: You really think it's a Java issue? I bet it has more to do with you only using integers to represent floating-point results.

Comment: Pro tip: When you're new to some technology, 99.99999999999999% of the time what you think is a glaring bug is really a faulty expectation on your part. I'm speaking from experience.

Comment: @bernie Truth. My personal definition of a _bug_ is "something you didn't expect".

Comment: I started Java 3 years ago when I was 13, so I'm not exactly "new". However, in PHP it automatically converts ints to floats whenever necessary, so I assumed Java would do the same. My mistake.

Comment: @bernie: Pro tip: When you've been working with a technology for years and years, 99.9% of the time what you think is a glaring bug is *still* really a faulty expectation on your part :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: well played, Sir. To my chagrin I manage to do something like this nearly every day.

Comment: Java does not do any type conversions until necessary.  The / operator on two int values returns an int.  if you want to deal with the remainder there's the % (usually called mod) operator.  If you want floating point artithmetic, you have to cast the individual values so that it uses the floating point version of the / operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast one of the divide operands to `double`, and the `double` type will propagate up through the calculation:

```
System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (27 - 20));
```

**Further reading**

- [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [Primitive Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) - this is from the Java Language Specification. Dry but perfectly accurate information (very useful). The heart of the matter:

> If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation, even if the other is integral.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why does it behave in such a way that it needs you to explicitly define it as a double?

Comment: Because "(240 - 20)" is integer value and "(160 - 300)" is also integer

Comment: The types of all your numbers are `int` by default. You can't represent decimal values with an `int`, and Java doesn't automatically change the result type for you. For example `1 / 3` is equal to `0`. Will add  reading links in the answer..

Comment: @JRunner added some links. Hopefully the second one will answer many questions.

Answer (score 1):

An Integer value is a whole number such as `1,2,3,4, etc`.  If you intend for the result to contain a decimal point `.` you need to use a `double` or a `float`.

The following code produces the correct results:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (27 - 20)); 
      System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (26 - 20)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use only integer values in your calculations and you'll receive the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
System.out.println(300 +((double)(160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (27 - 20));

System.out.println(300 + ((double)(160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (26 - 20));
```

The casting to double needs to happen before the division, else the value returned is 0 in the above cases

Answer (score 0):

`((160 - 300) / (240 - 20)) * (26 - 20)` = `((-140/220) * (26 - 20))` = `(0 * 6)` = 0

This is because all the numbers are integers and the expression is evaluated as integer, and the `(-140/220)` evaluates to `0` therefore there is nothing added to the value `300`

Typecast the division to `double` like:

`((160 - 300) / (double)(240 - 20)) * (26 - 20)`

or simply represent any number with a decimal point which will force the entire expression to be upcasted and evaluated as a floating point.

`((160 - 300) / (240 - 20.0) * (26 - 20)`

Comment: A detailed explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ths formula which gives 295.54545454545456

```
System.out.println(300 + ((160d - 300) / (240 - 20)) * (27 - 20));
```

You might also read up a little bit how Java calculates expressions and type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

Integer equation only output integer answer.

For example, `1 / 2 = 0` with a remainder of 1

In this case, use casting as paislee suggested, or use the example below:

```
System.out.println(300 + ((160 - 300) / (240.0 - 20)) * (27 - 20));
```

Put a x.0 implicitly suggests that it is a double.